# Biblioteca sys - maxsize

Tags: python

Para que serve essa função `sys.maxsize`?

```
import sys

Menor: int = sys.maxsize
```

O que significa esta expressão?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é uma função, é uma constante. Ela indica o maior valor endereçável que esta implementação do Python suporta. Em 32 bits deve ser 4.294.967.295 e em 64 bits deve ser 18.446.744.073.709.551.615.

[Documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize).

Comment: Muito, obrigado!